# How to mock callback function in Jest which triggers in redux-saga using redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I have a dispatched action in React Component and saga listen this action and do async call

COMPONENT: `dispatch(getGroups, (success) => setStatus(success))`

ACTION: `getGroups(state, action: { payload: (success: boolean) => void }) {},`

SAGA `yield takeLatest(getGroups, getGroupsList);`

```
function* getGroupsList(action) {
  try {
    const groupsListResponse = yield call(enrollmentService.getGroupsList);
    action.payload(true);
  } catch (error: any) {
    action.payload(false);
  }
}
```

So, I just don't know how I could mock returned callback inside redux-saga?

Comment: It's not clear. What does the "returned callback" mean?

Comment: I mean that I push callback function to the saga from component and saga call this function with true or false argument. which I handle in the component